# How to set the style for XAML GeometryDrawing?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a XAML icon as seen below. I use it as part of the ImageSource of a Button. How can I create a style so I can pass the Brush color from my Button so I can have different colors of the same icon?

```
<DrawingImage x:Key="ico_save">
        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="SteelBlue" Geometry="F1 M 20.5833,20.5833L 55.4167,20.5833L 55.4167,55.4167L 45.9167,55.4167L 45.9167,44.3333L 30.0833,44.3333L 30.0833,55.4167L 20.5833,55.4167L 20.5833,20.5833 Z M 33.25,55.4167L 33.25,50.6667L 39.5833,50.6667L 39.5833,55.4167L 33.25,55.4167 Z M 26.9167,23.75L 26.9167,33.25L 49.0833,33.25L 49.0833,23.75L 26.9167,23.75 Z" />
        </DrawingImage.Drawing>
    </DrawingImage>
```

---

Here is how I use it:

```
    <RibbonButton x:Name="RibbonButtonSave"
                                      Label="Save"
                                      LargeImageSource="{StaticResource ico_save}"
                                      ToolTip="Save as HTML" />

In order to have different colored-icons I want to be able to do something like this:

 <RibbonButton x:Name="RibbonButtonSaveRed"
                                      Label="Save"
                                      LargeImageSource="{StaticResource ico_save}"
Color="Red"
                                      ToolTip="Save as HTML" />


 <RibbonButton x:Name="RibbonButtonSaveBlue"
                                      Label="Save"
                                      LargeImageSource="{StaticResource ico_save}"
Color="Blue"
                                      ToolTip="Save as HTML" />
```

Comment: _"...pass the Brush color from my Button..."_.  Could you clarify that?

Comment: I edited the original questions. I hope this clarifies the confusion.

Comment: Why don't you create multiple `DrawingImage` resources with the colors you want?

Comment: Thank you jstreet for the comment. But duplicating DrawingImage is what I am trying to avoid here.

Comment: Think about it: how would you do the same thing with code behind? You would need multiple instances of `DrawingImage` with different colors. There's no magic in XAML, it is going to duplicate it for you behind the scenes.

Comment: Let's say, just for the sake of argument, you have 1000 `RibbonButton` with a RED icon and 1000 more with BLUE icon. So, you would have 2000 `RibbonButton` referring only 2 `DrawingImage` resources.